# Adding new items is extremely slow

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm exploring Nativescript. Maybe I don't understand something but adding new items with this simple code takes more than 1 second on my Android! The same code with divs executes instantly in any Web browser. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Home" />
        <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" backgroundColor="lightgray"
        width="100%" height="100%">
            <Button text="Add" @tap="click" />
            <Label v-for="item of items"  width="20" height="20"
            backgroundColor="red" marginLeft="5" marginTop="5" />
        </WrapLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                items: []
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            
        },
        methods: {
            click(e) 
            {
                for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    this.items.push({i}); 
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    .home-panel {
        vertical-align: center;
        font-size: 20;
        margin: 15;
    }
</style>
```

**Edit**
Ok, I was running the code from playground. Now I installed nativescript locally and the code executes several times faster. But still far from being instantaneous. Also, I tried to add items created programmatically that is without vuejs to make sure that vuejs is not the one to blame. Indeed, there's some problem with nativescript itself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're causing re-renderings after every single push, which can be expensive. What about creating those 30 items, holding that in a temp array, and then spread pushing it instead?

```
methods: {
    click(e)  {
        const newItems = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            newItems.push({i}); 
        }

        this.items.push(...newItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's as slow as my original code. For clarification: I run the code  from the playground.